Excel VBA code completes a nested loop, but doesn't reach the line following
Below is the essence of the sub in question. The code within the nested loops runs correctly. When the loops complete, however, control does not pass to the statement following the loops. Instead, the sub acts as if there were an 'Exit Sub' there. Any suggestions?
    For yr = firstYear To finalYear
        For i = 1 To 12
           ...
        Next i
    Next yr
    MsgBox "Loop completed"

The values of firstYear and finalYear are 2014 and 2024, respectively. I have reinstalled MS 365 and rebooted my PC, which is running Windows 10. When I step thru the code in the VBA editor, everything works until I reach i=12 and yr=finalYear and complete the code for that loop, at which point the next statement highlighted by the debugger is the first line of a diffferent. I know the code inside the loop runs correctly because there are MsgBox statements therein, and they appear as expected. The code loops thru 11 worksheets (or years on one worksheet) and 12 months each, but does not change anything on the worksheets. I know the outer loop runs because of an Application.StatusBar message. I added a timestamp at the end of each worksheet to verify this, which worked once when called for a single worksheet, but not otherwise. I added some comments, and now I get a run-time error in a function called by this sub:
Run-time error '1004'

Unable to get the Find property of the Worksheetfunction class.

This use of the Find method has been working here and elsewhere many times previously. In an earlier version, after the first time thru the inner loop, the debugger showed the active statement to be the first line of a function called from a different worksheet. I assumed this was due to the calc mode being automatic, but did not step beyond this point at that time. I added Application.Calculation=xlManual at the start of the sub, but the sub failed, after which the calc mode was still manual because the .Calculation=xlAutomatic at the end of the sub was not reached. I made some changes to the .StatusBar message, which had no effect for a single worksheet (still got run-time error), but for multiple worksheets the sub completes the inner loop (verifyed by timestamps) for 2014, then dies for an unknown reason. The calculation mode makes no difference. It seems that any change, no matter how trivial (eg, adding a comment) causes a change in behavior. Now, with the above run-time error, I haven't been able to investigate further. I am more confused and frustrated than ever.

There's not much here to go on. What are the values of firstYear and finalYear before entering the loop? How do you know the code inside the loop runs correctly?

So your saying that the code doesn't fire the MsgBox line? What did you find when you used various debugging tools like stepping through/break points/watches? Your response should be edited into your question.
